Computational complexity of approximating partition functions
I would like to understand the computational complexity of approximating the partition function of 2D Ising model with complex external magnetic field and complex couplings for the following cases:

At high temperature
At low temperature

Also for 2D Ising models:

Non-uniform but positive couplings with and without magnetic field
Non-uniformly chosen couplings from $\pm1$ with and without magnetic field

So far, I was able to gather the following information.
2D Ising model with complex external magnetic field and complex couplings at high temperature
This is my current line of thought. I am using High-Temperature Series Expansion so. Because the system is disordered, the interactions between spins decay rapidly with distance, and higher-order interactions contribute less significantly. The number of new terms introduced in each higher order is related to the number of additional interactions considered. Because interactions are weak and relatively independent at high temperatures, the complexity of interactions grows linearly, and hence the number of terms in the expansion grows linearly. The computational complexity should depend on the order of expansion, lattice size, additional factor for complex arithmetic, and precision requirement. So, it will be along the line of O(number of terms X Lattice size), right?
2D Ising model with complex external magnetic field and complex couplings at low temperature
I am using Low-Temperature Series Expansion. But number of terms will be an exponential function of the order of expansion. The rest of the calculation will be the same as above.
Non-uniform but positive couplings with magnetic field
Should it be $O(linear size \times number of configuration)$?
Non-uniform but positive couplings without magnetic field
Same as above.
Non-uniform but positive couplings chosen from $\pm 1$ with magnetic field
Same as above.
Non-uniform but positive couplings chosen from $\pm 1$ without magnetic field
Same as above.
Any intuition how I can take the nuances into account and do more explicit calculations?

The 2D Ising model can solve a dual of the traveling salesman problem, so its classical computational complexity should be at least NP-hard.

@James, in general, approximating the partition function would be #P-hard, right?

Given that classical models don't have a sign problem, it should be possible to get (multiplicative) approximations to the partition function in $\mathrm{P^{NP}}$ by Stockmeyer's approximate counting.

@OmarShehab I not really sure what you would like to compute, but if it is equivalent to the TSP there are approximation algorithms that are $O(n^2)$, which gives reasonably good answers though not the best possible solution. https://www.shiksha.com/online-courses/articles/the-traveling-salesman-problem

Should this be asked at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory ?

Hi Omar Shehab. By the word complex in the phrase complex magnetic field, do you mean complex numbers or complexity?

@Qmechanic, complex number
